# Issue on Getting clicked TR from TABLE using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

[image]

I designed this using HTML Table, On Button hover Im showing two buttons(Delete,Set).I want to perform two actions,that is
1) When I click Delete Button,I want to delete that particular table row
2)When I click Set Button,I want to set the particular rows ListBox's selected value in Label and remove ListBox's.

My Table code:

```
<table id="dataTable" border="1px" bordercolor="lightgrey" cellpadding="10">
<caption>Monday</caption>
<tr bordercolor="grey"><td align="center">open</td><td align="center">close</td><td>
<ul class="dropv">
   <li> <a href="#"> <button type="button" name="btn[]">Button</button></a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><input type="image" name="new[]" class="newbtn" onclick="addRow()" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/new.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>

     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>

</td></tr>
<tr class="dasd"><td><select id ="t" style="width: 60px;">  
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i<=24;$i++)
    {
        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
    }
?>
</select> : <select style="width: 60px;">
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i<=24;$i++)
    {
        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
    }
?>
</select></td><td><select style="width: 60px;">
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i<=24;$i++)
    {
        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
    }
?>
</select> : <select style="width: 60px;">
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i<=24;$i++)
    {
        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
    }
?>
</select></td>
<td >
<ul class="dropv">
   <li> <a href="#"> <button type="button" name="btnt[]">Button</button></a>    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><input type="button" value="Delete" name="ok[]" class="delbtn[]" onclick="delval(this)" /> </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><input type="button" value="Set" name="set[]" class="tickbtn[]" onclick="setval(this)" /></a></li>

     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>

</td></tr>
</table>
```

My Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delval(e) {
     var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if(rowCount > 2)
         table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);

}
function setval(e) {

     var as = document.getElementById("t");

     var select = document.createElement("label");
     select.innerHTML = as.options[as.selectedIndex].value;
     as.parentNode.replaceChild(select, as);

}
</script>
```

Delete Button only works for last row delete,I also cant able to find the current row where button click is performed???

Comment: better have delete button in each row

Comment: yes im having delete button and set button in each row's last button column's hover,I had shown only one Button hover in image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your function....

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: yes its working!!! now as i mentioned my second issue was there     2) When I click Set Button,I want to set the particular rows ListBox's selected value in Label and remove that row ListBox's

Answer (score 0):

I think it will better for you to use jQuery. Than you can find parent row just by:

```
$(this).parent('tr')
```

This is clicked button, and from taht button you go to parent tr - your actual tr that you want to delete.

Let's say in that way:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

Should work fine for you.

Comment: its not deleting the row, may be you can check my code once again

Answer (score 0):

Add an id or class to the <*tr*> tag and reference it when you want to delete the row.

Comment: as long as you give a id to the row dynamically you can adress it this way. The result is the same at the end. The id just helps you to adress the row without using jquery or similiar frameworks to do things linke next, parent, ...

Otherwise try jquery and use the suggestions from Kamil-Debowski or mano

Answer (score 0):

try ths , put text field near select option and hide them using javascript,put id for every select option

```
$('#texthere').hide();
 $("#a").change(function () {
   $('#texthere').show();
    var selectedItem = $("#a option:selected");
    $("#texthere").val(selectedItem.text());
        $('#a').hide();
});
```

demo---http://jsfiddle.net/ppSv4/4/

Comment: not for one element i want to do this for all listboxes in a row, how to do this?